# WPF Button Background Change on Click and Reset to original when another button in same StackPanel Clicked.

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a StackPanel with a few buttons. I want to change the color of a button when clicked and reset it to the original when another button in StackPanel is clicked. Is it possible with a single style applied on StackPanel or I have to create Style for each button? If yes then how.

Here is the code of Style applied to StackPanel but this changes the color of the button but does not reset it on clicking another button.

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="GlobalStackPanelStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource FlatStackPanel}">
      <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Style.Triggers> 
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Green"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>                           
                    </Trigger>                        
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Hi, I am having small confusion with your statement - "I want to change the color of a button when clicked and reset it to the original when another button in StackPanel is clicked" - You mean the first button should be back to its own color and 2nd button to <your own color> and so on...?

Comment: Or just the first button to reset to its own color and let other buttons as it is? If your question is my second statement then you can easily do it with a bool property in your ViewModel and then create a data trigger and based on the value (true/false), change the color of the first button. So on every button click, you need to toggle the boolean property value.

Comment: There is a color that denotes button is active and another that denotes inactive. All the buttons are initially in Inactive color. So if the first button is clicked then its color should be changed to active and when another button is clicked the color of first button changes to inactive and color of second button changes to active color.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response. Here are the steps that you can follow to get the required output.

Assuming you are following MVVM design pattern.

1. Create buttons in .xaml and bind command to each button as shown below,

   ```
        <Button Height="32" Width="180" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button 1"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="Button 1">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButton1Active}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButton1Active}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <Button Height="32" Width="180" Grid.Column="2" Content="Button 2"
                Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="Button 2">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButton2Active}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButton2Active}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
   ```

Note: You can add how many buttons you want to add to above xaml.

2. Create 2 boolean properties and set the values of those boolean properties from your ClickCommand method.

   ```
    private bool isButton1Active;
    private bool isButton2Active;

    public bool IsButton1Active
    {
        get { return isButton1Active; }
        set { isButton1Active = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public bool IsButton2Active
    {
        get { return isButton2Active; }
        set { isButton2Active = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
   ```
3. Here is code for command - Add it in your ViewModel

   ```
    private UICommand _clickCommand;
    public UICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get { return _clickCommand; }
    }
   ```
4. Write below statement in your view model constructor

   ```
    public YourViewModelConstructor()
    {
        _clickCommand = new UICommand(OnClick);
    }
   ```
5. Here is the method that is bound to ClickCommand

   ```
    private void OnClick(object parameter)
    {
        switch(parameter.ToString())
        {
            case "Button 1":
                IsButton1Active = true;
                IsButton2Active = false;
                break;

            case "Button 2":
                IsButton2Active = true;
                IsButton1Active = false;
                break;
        }
    }
   ```
6. Here is the code for my UICommand class

   ```
    public class UICommand : ICommand
    {
       private readonly Action<object> _execute;
       private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

       public UICommand(Action<object> onExecuteMethod, Func<bool> onCanExecuteMethod = 
            null)
      {
        _execute = onExecuteMethod;
        _canExecute = onCanExecuteMethod;
      }

      public bool IsCanExecute { get; set; }

      #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { if (_canExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { if (_canExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        IsCanExecute = (_canExecute == null || _canExecute());
        return IsCanExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
    }
   ```

I assume you know on how to setting datacontext to your window.

This examples gives you an idea on how to achieve functionality by creating some properties created in your ViewModel and bind a command in your View to ViewModel Command property and invoke click command by passing Command Parameter.

Still have any doubts after implementing the solution, kindly let us know.